# Rexster to visualize Titan Graph using DynomoDB as storage backend

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, titan, rexster

I just started using Titan Graph DB. I want to use the AWS DynamoDB as the Storage Backend. I have set up Dynamo DB locally using the steps mentioned on  [Installing and Running the DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.TitanDB.DownloadingAndRunning.html)

All the steps have been successfully completed.
I now want to visualize the graph (Marvel Universe Social Graph), using Rexster.

I have downloaded Rexster and set it up.
From what i have read, i understand that entries have to be made to  config/rexster.xml file to conect it to my graph DB . I cannot find what exactly needs to be put in to it, if DynamoDB is to be used as backend. Can someone tell me the exact steps i should follow when dynamoDB is used as storage backend?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Titan 1.0.0 as the document you referenced states, then you will not be able to use this with Rexster because Rexster is not compatible with the underlying TinkerPop 3.0.1 version that is used.

Rexster is compatible with TinkerPop 2.x, and TinkerPop 2.x is out of service.

Comment: Any free visualizing tool you can suggest of which works with Titan 1.0.0?

Comment: Since Titan 1.0 is based on Apache TinkerPop 3, you can try using [Gephi](https://gephi.org/). Be aware that there is a [TinkerPop bug](https://github.com/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/pull/308) that are being addressed for the latest Gephi 0.9 release. For the version of TinkerPop packaged with Titan, support is only for Gephi 0.8. Please refer to the TinkerPop docs for [Gephi streaming](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#gephi-plugin).